# Newton's method with negative roots and variable in the exponent

Tags: calculus

Use Newton's method to apporzimate the indicated root of the equation correct to six decimal places. The negative root of $e^x = 4-x^2$

I do not know what a negative root is nor do I really know what I am supposed to do. I am guessing raise everything by loge.

Comment: A negative root $x$ of a function $f$ is a value $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x < 0$ and $f(x)=0$

Comment: Also the question is not really different from the one you just asked ( http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76421/newtons-method-problem ), didn't you learn anything from the answer? :-/

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: What Listing said was that a "negative root" is a root that happens to be a negative number. A root of an equation is a *solution* to the equation. So they are asking you to find the negative value of $x$ that makes $e^x = 4-x^2$ true.

Answer (score 4):

The negative root is the one where $x<0$.  This equation has two roots, one near $x=-2$ and one near $x=1$.  You could look at [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%204-x%5E2-exp%28x%29)

You are solving $0=4-x^2-e^x$.  For Newton's method, you need to take the derivative, find a starting value like $x_0=-2$, then iterate $x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}$ until the change in $x$ gets smaller than $10^{-6}$

Newton's method works well when you start close to the root as long as the derivative doesn't get too small.  In this case, I find convergence within three cycles.

Comment: I don't understand what is happening, I keep using it and I am getting numbers smaller than 1 eventually.

Comment: You should read about Newton's method.  The basic idea is that you have a point on the graph that is close to the root.  The derivative gives the tangent line to the graph, and you project that tangent down to the x axis for your next guess at the root.  Then continue until you are as close as you want to be.

Comment: I know all about it but it just doesn't seem to work when I use it.

Answer (score 0):

e^x=4-x^2
**Subtract** e^x
4-x^2-e^x=0
**Take Derivative**
-2x-e^x=0

plug this formula into the graphing calculator:

x-((4-x^2-e^x)/(-2x-e^x))
 (NOTE - this formula can be used with any Newton's method problem when needing to find roots: x-(original fx/derivative of fx)

From the graphing screen, hit 2nd + Trace, select Value, put x=-1. The y-value given on the screen is the "new" x-value. Now do 2nd + Trace again this time typing in the "new" x-value, the new given y-value is the next "new" x-value. Keep doing this over and over until the y-values stop growing/shrinking.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Reagrds